# Javascript High Score Table

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently unsure of how to go about doing this one thing in particular.

I have a high score table that currently displays the scores for each individual run at the game, up to a max of 10 scores.

What I need to do now is to hook in the ability to attach a name to that high score, which would be done when you obtain said high score.

Any thoughts?

My current set up is as follows:

`highscoreList` is an array that hold 10 arrays of `highscoreLine`.

`highscoreLine` is an array that contains the 7 numbers to draw as the visual representation of the high score table itself.

`highScores` is an array that contains the high scores themselves.

Here is the loop that is actually drawing the numbers.

```
for (var h = 0; h < highscoreList.length; ++h)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < highscoreList[h].length; ++i)
    {
        highscoreList[h][i].frameList = highscoreDigits[getDigit(highScores[h], i)].frameList;
        highscoreList[h][i].inbetweensList = highscoreDigits[getDigit(highScores[h], i)].inbetweensList;
    }
}
```

Comment: where are the names coming from?

Comment: Make `highscoreList` an array of objects: `{name:highscore_name, highscoreLine:array}`

Comment: Would making `highscoreList` an array of objects work with sorting the lines? It would need to be sorted by the score value

Comment: If you add a score value to the object yes, it can be sorted by score value

Comment: Alright I don't see why that wouldn't work. Make it an answer and I'll give you a fancy green check mark

Comment: Just here to agree with juvian.

Comment: Answer made, good luck with your proyect. @ecMode haha thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make highscoreList an array of objects: `{name:highscore_name, highscoreLine:array}`

If you want to sort the array by some kind of value, this is an example:

```
var highscoreList=[
   {score:2, name:'John', highscoreLine:[3,1,4,5,4,3,2]},
   {score:5, name:'John B', highscoreLine:[3,1,4,5,2,3,3]},
   {score:10, name:'John C', highscoreLine:[3,1,4,5,7,6,8]},
   {score:4, name:'John', highscoreLine:[3,1,4,5,9,8,7]}
];

highscoreList.sort(function(a,b){return a.score < b.score});
console.log(highscoreList)
```